# Display error message to user (node.js)

Tags: node.js, express

So I've been trying to research online for solutions, and none of them seem to work either because I'm doing it wrong, or they don't work in my situation.

I have a webpage which gives the user a place to enter email/pass etc. When they press the submit, it calls a post function, which has all the validation contained within it. Like so:

```
app.post('/check', function(req, res){
    function emailCheck(email){
        //when theres an error: console.log(error), and return false
    }

    function passCheck(password){
        //when theres an error: console.log(error), and return false
    }

    if (passCheck == true && emailCheck == true){
        //enter user into database
    }
}
```

When there is an error, I want it to be displayed to the user, either by use of popup box, or just text positioned under the sign up box.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: what view engine are you using?

Comment: @Alex All I'm using at the moment is HTML and node.js. Not sure if that's what you wanted?

Comment: Do you using some framework (Express, etc)? What error you could catch? With express, it's possible catch some http errors, as 404 or 502, in each request...

Comment: @LucasCosta Oh, yes, I'm using express.

Answer (score 2):

I would make an ajax request from the client to the server. If the validation fails you can send data specifying the problem to the client and do what you'd like with it.

Comment: Would this then require me making all the validation on the client side, rather than using the server?

Comment: No, an example would have the server do the validation logic and return what fields are incorrect to the client and the client can process that information.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, can you point me in the right direction? I've been researching of how to do this through AJAX but can't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
   //register User on post request from register form
router.post("/register", function(req, res){
    var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username});
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err){
           // console.log(err.message);
            req.flash("error", err.message);
            return res.render("register");
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
             req.flash("success","You created a new User Account " +user.username);
           res.redirect("/campgrounds"); 
        });
    });
});
```

you can Install: **npm install flash-connect**

and use **error.message** in console log to display the errors